# Drop down custom action

Tags: 2010, dropdown

I've tried to create drop down custom action for some time without any success and Google also can't help me. Anybody could to share example how to use [DropDown Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff458462%28v=office.14%29.aspx) as custom action?

Thx for help.

**UPD 1**:

Here is a code of my custom action, Button in this custom action works fine, but when I change it to DropDown I got error:

```
<CustomAction
   Id="Ribbon.Library.Actions.PrintTaskCard"
   Location="CommandUI.Ribbon.DisplayForm"
   RegistrationId="7006"
   RegistrationType="List"
   Title="Print">
<CommandUIExtension>
  <CommandUIDefinitions>
    <CommandUIDefinition
      Location="Ribbon.ListForm.Display.Manage.Controls._children">
      <!--<Button
        Id="PrintTaskCard"
        Command="PrintTaskCard"
        Description="Print"
        LabelText="Print"
        Sequence="1020"
        Image32by32="/_layouts/images/print.png"
        TemplateAlias="o1"/>-->

      <DropDown
        Id="PrintTaskCard"
        Width="100">
        <Menu>
          <MenuSection>
            <Controls>
              <Button Id="PrintTaskCardB"
                      Command="PrintTaskCard"
                      Description="Print"
                      LabelText="Print"
                      Sequence="1020"
                      Image32by32="/_layouts/images/print.png"/>
            </Controls>
          </MenuSection>
        </Menu>
      </DropDown>
    </CommandUIDefinition>
  </CommandUIDefinitions>
  <CommandUIHandlers>
    <CommandUIHandler
      Command="PrintTaskCard"
      CommandAction="javascript: printTaskCardClicked('{SiteUrl}','{ListId}','{ItemId}');"
      EnabledScript="javascript: printTaskCardEnable('{ItemId}');"/>
  </CommandUIHandlers>
</CommandUIExtension>
```

**UPD 2**:
I need to create DropDown menu like in image below in Ribbon Toolbar:

[Sorry, I haven't need reputation to add images in posts, so here is a link to image, that illustrates what I need to implement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fcNV.jpg)

Comment: could you share your code?

Comment: @SalvatoreDiFazio I've updated description of problem

Comment: I think you need to use a `SplitButton` if you want to match the image in your link. [MSDN SplitButton Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff458392(v=office.14).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I have done this in the Edit Control Block; If you are trying to create a drop down in the Ribbon, I cannot help you, but [Chris O'Brien has a fantastic walk-through that you might find helpful](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2010/02/ribbon-customizations-dropdown-controls.html).

[image: Adding an entry to the Edit Control Block]

code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CustomAction Id="ApproveContractECB"
                Location="EditControlBlock"
                Title="Approve Contract Request"
                RegistrationType="List"
                RegistrationId="100"
               ImageUrl="/_layouts/ContractApproval/img/approve_comment.png">
    <UrlAction Url="javascript:OpenPopUpPageWithTitle('{SiteUrl}/Lists/Contract%20Approval%20State/NewForm.aspx?ContractTitle={ItemId}', RefreshOnDialogClose, 800, 600,'Approve or Reject Contract Request')"/>
  </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

Comment: Thank you for advice, but it's not exactly what I need to implement. I've added image that illustrates what I need to implement.

Comment: The link that I posted is part of a series, his second article in the series describes how to add new options to existing groups.  http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2010/01/adding-ribbon-items-into-existing.html